# On the product topology

Tags: general-topology, infinite-product

I know that the product topology on a collection of topologies $X_i$ is defined by the basis
$$ B = \left \{ \Pi \, U_i : \text{Finitely many } U_i \text{ are open in } X_i, \text{ all other } U_i = X_i  \right \}.$$

Why is this said to be the basis of $X = \Pi X_i$ and not simply the topology for $X$? The union of any two elements in $B$ is simply going to be another element of $B$. What am I missing?

Comment: Not really, even in simplest possible product of two topological space, say $\mathbb{R}^2$ union of two rectangles aren't necessarily rectangles themselves.

Comment: Of course. Dumb question. My tired brain forgot how unions distribute with products.

Comment: This is called the Tychonoff product topology, which has been found to be very useful. There are other product topologies, such as the box product topology, and (when each  X_is is a metric space) the uniform topology (the topology of uniform convergence),

Answer (score 2):

The collection $B$ **is** closed under finite intersections, and covers $X$. So it is a base for *some* topology on $X$ which we call the product topology by definition.

Even finite unions of such rectangles need not be open at all, consider the plane. And an open circle in that plane is a union of (infinitely many) open rectangles, but certainly not in $B$. So $B$ is not a topology, merely a base for one. But to describe the topology it's enough to know a base for it (this already determines continuity, convergence, compactness etc.)